# KeyError when using .format to structure an expression

Tags: python, maya

I am using `.format` to edit and add an expression to an attribute.
I will get a `KeyError` when trying to execute the code:

```
modi_expr = """
    if (frame < 6) {
        {0}.frameExtension=6;
    }
    else if (frame > 73) {
        {0}.frameExtension=73;
    }
    else{
        {0}.frameExtension=frame;
    }
""".format('planeShape2')
```

Whereas if I used `%` as follows, while it works, it requires me to write 3 times of the same variable.

```
expr_to_use = """
    if (frame < 6) {
        %s.frameExtension=6;
    }
    else if (frame > 73) {
        %s.frameExtension=73;
    }
    else{
        %s.frameExtension=frame;
    }
""" % ('planeShape2', 'planeShape2', 'planeShape2')
```

If using `%` is the way to go, is there a way that I can write it once? If not, are there a better alternative way of approaching this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{{` and `}}` to escape the non-formatting braces.

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.

```
modi_expr = """
    if (frame < 6) {{
        {0}.frameExtension=6;
    }}
    else if (frame > 73) {{
        {0}.frameExtension=73;
    }}
    else{{
        {0}.frameExtension=frame;
    }}
""".format('planeShape2')

print(modi_expr)
```

Or you can also use f-strings for python >= 3.6

```
var = 'planeShape2'

modi_expr = f"""
    if (frame < 6) {{
        {var}.frameExtension=6;
    }}
    else if (frame > 73) {{
        {var}.frameExtension=73;
    }}
    else{{
        {var}.frameExtension=frame;
    }}
"""
```

The output will be

```
 if (frame < 6) {
        planeShape2.frameExtension=6;
    }
    else if (frame > 73) {
        planeShape2.frameExtension=73;
    }
    else{
        planeShape2.frameExtension=frame;
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! But can I kindly ask if the use of double curly brackets, are they generally for 'mel-based' commands then?

Comment: I have added a reference to the docs, they are used to escape single braces in the format string, also unsure what is `mel-based` commands?

Comment: it is not related to mel. {{ is pure pythonic when you use format (you could be tempted to use the traditionnal \ but it doesn't work for format). @DeveshKumarSingh, mel is a language inside maya software, he is modifying a mel based script with python where { is used for indentation. Out of curiosity, why not using directly python rather than mel ?